# VSCODE: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Tags: visual-studio-code

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
VS Code Version: 1.32.3

I can't install any extensions for my vs code. When I click "install", the error

> "Cannot read property 'local' of undefined"

I also tried to install manually, and it doesn't work too.

[image: Error image]

Comment: What`s the error you are getting ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is most probably because Code doesn't have privilege to write to the extension folder, which is by default ~/.vscode/extension.

The following command from terminal will fix it:

```sh
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.vscode
```

Comment: It is chown , not chmod.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 18.04 and Visual Studio Code Version: 1.33.1

Comment: I haven't been able to see what extensions I had installed or install any new ones. Even trying to do the manual download and install did not work. This fixed both issues, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem on Windows 10. Permissions in my case were not the problem. Try clearing the contents extensions folder which can normally be found here;

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions
```

This fixed the issue for me.

If you're looking more details on any error that might be causing your problems, try the following steps to open the developer console to check for errors.

```
CTRL+SHIFT+P >> Developer: Toggle Shared Process
```

When I tried this I got the following errors (prior to clearing the extensions folder);

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Ryan\.vscode\extensions\.obsolete'
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) W: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Ryan\.vscode\extensions\.obsolete'
at t.push.scanUserExtensions.then.e (file:///C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:257:223)
```

[Visual Studio Code Windows Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmvNP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you get `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` in vscode, there is probably a custom setting in `C:\Users\myself\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json` with a reference to a thing that is no more available. In my case it was a changed theme name, so the old name could not be referenced any more.

After removing that setting, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please, install latest version of VSCODE and try to install extensions from VSIX. You will be fine with windows 10.

Comment: The OS is specified into the question so Windows 10 couldn't a part of the solution.